# Accidentally deleted VisualSVN Server repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

A developer from our office accidentally deleted the repository from the VisualSVN Server.

Every developer in the office has a copy of the files, so I'm not worried about the files. What I want to recover is the changes log.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Restore it from your backup. You do keep backups, right?

Comment: +1 for this, without backups you will most definitely be up a creek without a paddle especially for your source!

Comment: And find out how someone managed to accidentally delete the repository. I think you might have to secure that a bit better.

Comment: I agree, backups should be in place, but as someone else set this up, I am certain they do not exist. At least, how could I setup backups, henceforth?

Comment: Theo, the backup solution that is best for your situation depends entirely on the details of your situation. There is no one answer that will work for you. I would advise contacting a local system administration consulting practice with a good reputation to set something up for you.

At a minimum, you need weekly full backups and daily incremental with off-site storage of the backup media.

Comment: OK I wrote a quick batch file, to take a new backup once a day, so at least, worst case we can go back a day.
Thank you Adam, and everyone else

Comment: Make sure you know how to backup a live SVN repository too. Don't just copy the files. Look into `svnadmin hotcopy` and `svnsync`.